# createNativeQuery - oci8 returns empty array

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework-modules

on a very simple entity :

```
class Users {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $userid;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $username;
}[...]
```

while trying to do a native query

```
    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addEntityResult('Application\Entity\Users', 'u');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'test', 'username');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'userid', 'userid');
    $q = $objectManager->createNativeQuery('SELECT u.username as test, u.userid from users u where u.userid=17',$rsm);
    $result = $result->getResult();
```

$result returns an empty array with oracle (oci8 driver and pdo). 
With MySQL, all is ok. The databases are exactly the same between Oracle and MySQL, same tables, same columns.

The table 'users' is not empty, because when using DQL, it works. Works too when using addRootEntityFromClassMetadata() whith a native query.

It seems that the problem occurs only with oci8+addEntityResult().

Any idea ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the manual.

ResultSetMapping#addFieldResult();

The first parameter is the alias of the entity result to which the field result will belong. The second parameter is the name of the column in the SQL result set. Note that this name is case sensitive, i.e. **if you use a native query against Oracle it must be all uppercase**. The third parameter is the name of the field on the entity result identified by $alias into which the value of the column should be set.

```
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'TEST', 'username');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'USERID', 'userid');
```